# 配列ブロック（AddMInsertBlock)の書き方

Tags: vba, ijcad

AUTOCADからの移行作業を行っております
AUTOCADでは動作していたのですがIJCADでは下記のエラーが出ます

```
実行時エラー '-2147467259(8004005)':
'AddMInsertBlock'メソッドは失敗しました:'IGcadModelSpeace'オブジェクト
```

作業はブロックを1定の幅で並べるという物です（枠を作る）
素人のプログラムで見づらい所も多いですがご了承ください

```
Type Point
   Point(2) As Double
End Type

Dim PropertyIns As Point
PropertyIns.Point(0) = 100 * DwgScale
PropertyIns.Point(1) = 50 * DwgScale
PropertyIns.Point(2) = 0#

Dim InsertPoint As Variant
InsertPoint = PropertyIns.Point

Dim Blockobj As GcadObject
Set Blockobj = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.AddMInsertBlock(InsertPoint, Block_FileName, XScale, YScale, ZScale, Rotate, Rows, 1, FrameHeight, 0)
Blockobj.Layer = "0"
```

ヘルプを読んでも構文に問題はないと思っております

皆様にご教示いただきたく
よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IJCADでAddMInsertBlock()メソッドを実行した所、質問で書かれたのと同じエラーが出ました。
IJCADの不具合っぽいですね。

> 作業はブロックを1定の幅で並べるという物です（枠を作る）

ブロックを1定の幅で並べるのなら、AcadEntityのArrayRectangular()メソッドが
代用できるのではないでしょうか。
ArrayRectangular()メソッドは下記のように使います。

```
Type Point
   Point(2) As Double
End Type

Sub InsertBlockUsingArrayRectangular()
    Dim Blockobj As GcadBlockReference
    Dim Block_FileName As String
    Dim XScale, YScale, ZScale, Rotate, RowSpace, ColSpace As Double
    Dim XMin, YMin As Double
    Dim NumRows, NumColumns As Long
    Dim PropertyIns As Point
    
    XMin = 0
    YMin = 0
    '配列にしたい任意の図面ファイルを指定する。
    Block_FileName = "～.dwg"
    XScale = 1
    YScale = 1
    ZScale = 1
    Rotate = 0

    PropertyIns.Point(0) = XMin
    PropertyIns.Point(1) = YMin
    PropertyIns.Point(2) = 0#
    NumRows = 2
    NumColumns = 3
    ColSpace = 100
    RowSpace = 50
    Set Blockobj = ThisDrawing.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(PropertyIns.Point, Block_FileName, XScale, YScale, ZScale, Rotate)
    Call Blockobj.ArrayRectangular(NumRows, NumColumns, 1, RowSpace, ColSpace, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます

ご提案頂きました方法で見た目は問題ないのですが
個人的な趣味かもしれませんが配列複写の方がブロック（一体）にならず
複写した分のオブジェクト数になります

ArrayRectangularをヘルプにて調べてみましたがご教示いただいた情報以上は出てこず
配列複写等の変数を探してみたものの見つけることができませんでした

普通に配列複写コマンドにて作業を行うと一体化します
何かほかに設定等があるのでしょうか…

Comment: いいえ、IJCAD と AutoCAD ともに、ArrayRectangular()メソッドでブロックにする設定はないようです。

ArrayRectangular()メソッドで複写されたエンティティをブロックにする場合は、
別でブロックにする処理の実装が必要ですが、エンティティをブロックにする処理は実装できそうでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。部品表の枠を必要数記入するマクロですので配列をブロック化の処理をするのであれば、枠線を書いてブロック化してしまう方がスマートなのかもしれませんね。検討してみます。またわからないことが御座いましたらよろしくお願いいたします。